# NtCreateThreadEx not working on Windows 10 64bit 1909

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, code-injection, ntdll

Recently, I've studied dll injection techniques and I tested them. One of those was dll injection by CreateRemoteThread and NtCreateThreadEx. I investigated CreateRemoteThread and I fount out that it called NtCreateThreadEx internally. The thing is, CreateRemoteThread works fine but NtCreateThreadEx doesn't. The code is as follows.

```
struct NtCreateThreadExBuffer {
    ULONG Size;
    ULONG Unknown1;
    ULONG Unknown2;
    PULONG Unknown3;
    ULONG Unknown4;
    ULONG Unknown5;
    ULONG Unknown6;
    PULONG Unknown7;
    ULONG Unknown8;
};

typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI *LPFUN_NtCreateThreadEx) (
    OUT PHANDLE hThread,
    IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
    IN LPVOID ObjectAttributes,
    IN HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    IN LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
    IN LPVOID lpParameter,
    IN BOOL CreateSuspended,
    IN ULONG StackZeroBits,
    IN ULONG SizeOfStackCommit,
    IN ULONG SizeOfStackReserve,
    OUT LPVOID lpBytesBuffer
    );

...
HMODULE ntdll = GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll");
HMODULE kernel32 = GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll");
PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE ntCreateThreadExAddr = (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(ntdll, "NtCreateThreadEx");
lpfnLoadLibrary = GetProcAddress(kernel32, "LoadLibraryA");
NtCreateThreadExBuffer ntbuffer;
DWORD dwTmp1 = 0;
DWORD dwTmp2 = 0;
    
memset(&ntbuffer, 0, sizeof(NtCreateThreadExBuffer));
if (ntCreateThreadExAddr)
{
            ntbuffer.Size = sizeof(struct NtCreateThreadExBuffer);
            ntbuffer.Unknown1 = 0x10003;
            ntbuffer.Unknown2 = 0x8;
            ntbuffer.Unknown3 = &dwTmp2;
            ntbuffer.Unknown4 = 0;
            ntbuffer.Unknown5 = 0x10004;
            ntbuffer.Unknown6 = 4;
            ntbuffer.Unknown7 = &dwTmp1;
            ntbuffer.Unknown8 = 0;

        LPFUN_NtCreateThreadEx funNtCreateThreadEx = (LPFUN_NtCreateThreadEx)ntCreateThreadExAddr;
    
        NTSTATUS status = 0;
        status = funNtCreateThreadEx(
                &hThread,
                0x1FFFFF,
                NULL,
                hCurrp,
                (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)lpfnLoadLibrary,
                (LPVOID)param,
                FALSE,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL,
                &ntbuffer
            );  
}
```

The funny thing about this code is that error code is 31 and status is -1073741819. If anyone knows about this one, please teach me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strap it into a debugger and step through it to find out more about what's going on.

Comment: Why are you defining your own structure here full of "unknown" fields? That seems pretty strange.

Comment: I debugged this code but found nothing wrong before entering into syscall.

Comment: How do you know those values are correct?

Comment: I compared it with ones when CreateRemoteThread is called. But I am not so sure. I might be wrong.